# What is a good way to reference the directionality of an API integration in a succinct way?

Tags: technical-writing

I am responsible for product X. Product X has bi-directional connectivity with other systems A and B.

When I am referring to data coming from A in to X, I can say:

- "Inbound interface from A to X"
- "Inbound from A to X"

Or I can give the directionality a codename and say that:

- X1 = data coming in to X (implies from A)
- X2 = data leaving X (implies to A)

I don't find either of these to be elegant solutions. What is a good, succinct way to reference the directionality/flow of information between 2 systems?

Answer (score 0):

> - "Inbound interface from A to X"
> - "Inbound from A to X"

The informative part of both of these is **A to X**.

If I turned to this page from the index because I'm troubleshooting or looking up a specific function, I don't need to know anything else.

I certainly don't need to remember a code that is printed somewhere else in the book.

Answer (score 0):

A possible method is to use a direction indicator. This is the standard for the factory automation API:

E->H

E<-H

The first is "equipment to host". The second is "host to equipment".